# Negation of a Basic Logic Statement

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to negate the following english statement: All manatees are swimming.

```
m(x): x is a manatee
s(x): x is swimming
```

$\therefore (\forall x)(m(x) \land s(x))$

\begin{align*}
\neg [(\forall x)(m(x) \land s(x))] &\equiv \\
(\exists x) \neg(m(x) \land s(x)) &\equiv & \textbf{DeMorgan's Law}\\
\boxed{(\exists x) (\neg m(x) \lor \neg s(x))}
\end{align*}

The negation: *Some sea-creatures are not manatees or not swimming.*

My questions are:

1. Is my negation correct?
2. Can I infer that the domain is "sea-creatures" or do I need to say "there are things"**?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) That depends entirely on the context. Perhaps the domain of $x$  is all mammals with at least two distinct vowels in their English name. You never know. As for the laymen interpretation of the statement, your use of "some" could be interpreted as suggesting the existence of multiple $x$. The phrase "There is some $x$ that is either ..." would be more clear.

Comment: 1) No.  If some sea creatures are not manatees or not swimming that doesn't mean that it is not the case that all manatees are swimming. 2) It depends an what your universe was told to be.  I wouldn't assume that everything is supposed to be a sea creature.  Any way that doesn't matter because the question was about manatees specifically.

Comment: I think you are interpretting the original statement as "Every sea creature is a swimming manatee" in which case your negation is good.  But that *isn't* the statement.  The statement is "all manatees are swimming" so the negation should be "it isn't true that all manatees are swimming" or in other words.............

Comment: You have the negation of your sentence.  But your sentence is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation of the original statement is false. It should be $\forall x:m(x)\to s(x)$ or $\forall x:\neg m(x)\lor s(x)$. Then its negation is $\exists x:m(x)\land\neg s(x)$, or "there exists a manatee that is not swimming".

Answer (score 3):

> Is my negation correct?

Yes, your negation is correct

However, note that all manatees are swimming  translate to:

$$\forall x(m(x)\to s(x))$$

Negation is $\exists x(m(x)\land \neg s(x))$ translate to some meanatee is not swimming.

$\forall x(m(x)\land s(x))$ means everything (in the domain of $x$) is swimming meanatee.

> Can I infer that the domain is "sea-creatures" or do I need to say "there are things"?

Since on the first part it says $\forall x(m(x)\land s(x))$ means all manatees are swimming which is equivalent to $\forall x(m(x)\to s(x))$, that happens only if the domain of $x$ is all meanatees, that we can prove this two statement are the same:

\begin{align}
&\forall x(m(x)\land s(x))\\
\equiv&\forall x(\top\land s(x))\\
\equiv&\forall x(s(x))\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&\forall x(m(x)\to s(x))\\
\equiv&\forall x(\top\to s(x))\\
\equiv&\forall x(s(x))\\
\end{align}

Hence $\forall x(m(x)\land s(x))\equiv\forall x(m(x)\to s(x))$ when domain is all meanatees.